# Outlet suddenly not working

Tags: electrical

Came home from vacation to find five outlets not working all of a sudden. It's a 9 year old house. Checked breakers, loose wiring. Only different is one outlet is only wired for the bottom plug but nothing is wired for the top plug. This is unlike the others I have checked. The outlet test kit says that "Hot & Green are revered". But they wired the same as the good outlets reading "correct wiring".

Comment: It is probably a GFCI outlet tripped.  The outlet with just the bottom wired is at the end of the line, so does not have an extra cable going somewhere else.  Go find outlets with buttons on them.